# Cooldown Message not working on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a economy system for my bot, and a cooldown for the beg command. 
The command works, the cooldown works but it doesn't say anything when the command is on cooldown.

Here is the code :

```
getconbalanceAliases = "gc, getconbal"
getconbalanceDesc = "Earn Conbalance! This command has a 30 second cooldown."
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
@client.command(aliases=["gc","getconbal"])
async def getconbalance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author

    users = await get_bank_data()

    earnings = random.randrange(101)

    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} Got {earnings} coins!!')

    users[str(user.id)]["conbalance"] += earnings

    with open("conbalance.json",'w') as f:
        json.dump(users,f)


@getconbalance.error
async def getconbalance_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f"Slow it down bro",
    description = f"You look like a little baby when you beg.", 
    color = 0xf461ff)
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

    embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by  {ctx.author} at {current_time}")
    await ctx.reply(embed=embed,mention_author=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an event. On a cog, it will be:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_error(self,ctx,error):
     if isinstance(error,commands.CommandOnCooldown):
```

Comment: I am not using cog. Can you show me how to do it without cogs?

Comment: @MenIndo For outside cogs, we use ``@client.event``

Comment: @MenIndo Which means, the code will be:
```@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
      if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
```